# Get list applications which use data in Android

Tags: android

I would like to create data usage monitoring tool for Android. I have gone through some API available in Android SDK and found that TrafficStats class provides method to get data usage for a specific UID. I need to know whether there is a way i can identify when an applications starts sending or receiving data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess this might be what you want. [`ActivityManger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)) provides all the running task with its UID, and some other useful info, such as application info.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know whether there is a way i can identify when an applications starts sending or receiving data.

Not really, as that can happen at any point, and there are no events sent out to other apps (e.g., broadcasts) for this.

That being said, when the `TrafficStats` value for the UID changes between checks, you know it accessed the network.